# Can Don't Starve be played without Reign of Giants?

Tags: steam, dont-starve

I just bought the Reign of Giants expansion for Don't Starve today. However, can Don't Starve be played *without* the Reign of Giants now that I own it?

Comment: This is an excellent question. I hope you don't mind that I've edited it to improve the quality of the question and answer even further.

Comment: I agree with most of your improvements, thanks @Keavon

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When creating a new game, just click the "RoG" box so that it turns to a red X. This will disable Reign of Giants.

[image: RoG Enabled -> RoG Disabled]